# Angular 2 router title with parameter

Tags: angular

Assuming I use the following expression to set a page title for angular component in my router:

{ path: 'view-move/:moveName', component: ViewMoveComponent, data: {title:'View Move'} }

Assuming that I use router params to get the Move details including his name, how I can put the move name inside my title, so it would be like:

**View Move: Move name**

Update: I Tried:

```
import { BrowserModule, Title }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(public http: Http,private route: ActivatedRoute,private titleService: Title) {
this.titleService.setTitle("My Title");
  }
```

No title now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject the `TitleService` into your component and use its `setTitle` method.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html

Comment: `import { BrowserModule, Title }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(public http: Http,private route: ActivatedRoute,private titleService: Title) {
this.titleService.setTitle("My Title");
  }` don't set any title

Comment: You have to add the service to the providers array in your app module